# Is it possible to limit the number of user account password resets per day in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, citrix, password-policy

Windows domain environment here. We're looking at putting in a self-service password reset system (using Citrix Single Sign-on), and I'm trying to figure out if we can limit the number of password resets a user can initiate down to 2 per day.

I'm not sure that this can be done with Citrix Single Sign-on (correct me if I'm wrong), but is it possible to restrict this with an AD password policy, *without* preventing Administrators from being able to reset the password if the user calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The privilege path that the password reset system is taking is identical to what happens when an administrator resets the password; the service account that the self service software is using will be assigned the same rights.

It's a simple privilege against the user account, which overrides the password change rate-limiting restrictions in the password policy, as well as other aspects like password history restrictions.

So, no, a limit on resets per day would unfortunately need to be implemented and enforced in the self service tool.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the Minimum Password Age setting is close; unfortunately, from memory it takes an integer as a number of days that a password must be valid for, meaning 1 is the minimum.

It shouldn't prevent Admin-driven password resets, but will prevent users re-resetting the password after an Admin reset (at least, the docs for MinPasswordAge say so)